# maptplotlib imshow() does nothing

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I recently installed [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) distribution (with `sudo`, under `/usr/lib`).

However, when trying to execute the following lines:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
from numpy import zeros
pyplot.imshow(zeros((100, 100)))
```

Nothing happens (I expect to see a black screen). No error at all.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to tell matplotlib to `show` the plot (or save the figure to a file) after making it.

To display the plot on the screen, try adding `pyplot.show()` after your `imshow` line.

To save to a file, try `pyplot.savefig('myfig.png')`

Comment: Good! But then, why is it named "imshow"...? :-/

Comment: @EliasHasle I'm pretty sure that's terminology that `matplotlib` inherited from `matlab`

Answer (score 2):

if you want to see the `plot` and `imshow`, then activate interactive mode by:

`matplotlib.pyplot.ion()`

Then you would not have to do `show()` every time you want to see the plot updated.

`matplotlib.pyplot.ioff()`

will turn off interactive mode. Interactive mode will slow the program so when you have a lot to draw, `ion()` is not recommended.